# MySQL: Modifying output of a field for calculation

Tags: mysql, sql

I know calculating age from DOB is relatively simple but I have an issue with different data entry formats in the database. Also, I know this can be easier using PHP, but I don't know PHP and only have MySQL to work with.

The DOB entered into the DB is entered as "month/day/year" or "00/00/0000". But when calculating against today's date, the date would be formatted as "year-month-day" or "0000-00-00". Furthermore, the month placed in the DOB field can have either a one number month (1/01/1999) or a two number month (01/01/1999), so it's not consistent.

I am trying to use the below to utilize CONCAT, SUBSTRING and LOCATE to output the DOB in a better suited format for the age calculation. I think I'm close but not quite there. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
SELECT
CONCAT(SUBSTRING(APPU_DOB,-4,4),'-', SUBSTRING(APPU_DOB,LOCATE('/', APPU_DOB),1),'-',SUBSTRING(APPU_DOB,4,2))       
 FROM APPU_APP_USER
 JOIN APPL_APP ON APPU_APPL_ID = APPL_ID
       WHERE DATE_FORMAT(APPL_CREATE_DT, '%Y-%M-%D') >= '2014-01-01';
```

Comment: Impractical at best, but you should refactor your table to store APPU_DOB as a date type instead of a string type. Problems like the one you're facing can be avoided with proper typing.

Comment: is appu_dob a column here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `Concat` use `str_to_date` function.

```
select str_to_date( appu_dob, '%m/%d/%Y' ) as 'dob';
```

on `1/01/1999` it returns a valid date formatted object with value `1999-01-01`.
You can use it on other date *strings* that have single or two digit day or month numbers.

***Note***: To represent or refer a month, use small case `m` but not capital `M`, in the format pattern string.

And you should better redefine the data type of `appu_dob` field to `date`. So that you can easily apply date specific functions on it for any calculations.